# Use SQL Server Authentication to authenticate ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created an ASP.NET Web API that fetches some data from an SQL Server Database table and I am able to use windows authentication using [Authorize(Users = "\")] attribute. I want to change the authentication such that a user is authenticated to access the API using the same SQL server authentication user name and password. Is it possible? If yes then how do I configure this?

Comment: What do you mean by "...user is authenticated to access the API using the same SQL server authentication user name and password" ? Do you want to use authenticated user credentials to connect to SQL server?

Comment: I mean to access the Api, like using the api url in browser to view the data in json format, the user should be prompted to enter the SQL server credentials that he uses to login in SSMS.

Comment: IIS isn't going to prompt someone for sql server credentials. This will work for Windows accounts since IIS will issue a challenge/response, but never for SQL Server users. You would need another mechanism to do this securely

Comment: SQL Server accounts are not meant to be used to secure a web API. Web API/IIS can't understand them or check them in any way. Only SQL Server itself can do that. You need to think of something else. Perhaps switch your users to using Windows Authentication for both the API and the SQL Server, then the API can connect to SQL Server as if it was that user by passing through the same windows identity as was used to authenticate to the API. The other benefit is that no-one has to enter any passwords at all if they're a network user.

Comment: Although...why is a user connecting directly to an API manually? Where's the GUI layer? APIs are meant for other computers to connect to. The user should be accessing a GUI which then fetches data from the API and displays it in a user-friendly way.

Comment: ok..That answers the question. Yes off-course the idea is to allow client applications to use the api and display the data in a UI. The user name and password could be sent as headers. Will take your advice.